# CloudSQLとMySQLのユーザー一覧が一致しない

Tags: mysql, google-cloud

Djangoであるチャットボットの導入をgithubを見ながら行っているのですが、
CloudSQLの接続で詰まってしまい、調査をする中で下記疑問が解決しないため、教えていただけますと幸いです。

MySQLクライント上のユーザー一覧とcloudSQLコンソール上のユーザー一覧が一致しないことが理解が出来ません。cloudSQLへの接続方法が誤っているのかどうかも判別がつかずアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。コードは下記になります。

[こちら](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy?hl=ja])を参考にMySQLクライアントでCloudSQLインスタンスに接続をして調査をしてみたのですが、

```
> mysql -u root -p -S /cloudsql/michatbot-250809:us-central1:polls-instance2
Enter password: ************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 27 Server version: 8.0.17
```

↑でCloudSQLへの接続が成功してSQLクライアントが立ち上がったのかと思ったのですが、

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user; 
+------------------+-----------+ 
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+ 
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | 
| mysql.session    | localhost | 
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost | 
| test2            | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

一覧を表示させてみるとCloudSQL上のユーザー一覧と異なる結果が出てしまいます。
またユーザー作成を行ってみてもCloudSQL上には追加されず、こちらのSQLクライアント上で追加されるのみで、連動されていないように見えます。

アドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

Comment: mysqlの接続コマンドや、その結果の表示に記載間違いはないでしょうか？ そこで示されていMySQLのバージョンは8.0.17となっていますが、Cloud SQLではバージョン8を選択できないはずです。記載されている内容が正しいのであれば、別のMySQLサーバに接続されていることになります。

Comment: itmammothさん　コメントありがとうございます。記載自体はコマンドラインの記載をそのままコピペしているため間違っていないはずです。cloudsql～の記載はcloudsqlインスタンスの接続情報を入れているのですが違うMySQLに接続されてしまっているんですね。バージョン8を選べないということなのでどこかで設定を間違えているのかもしれません。確認してみます。

Comment: 自己解決いたしました。①MySQL8.0を過去インストールしていたようなので、それのアンインストール。②MySQL5.7のインストール　③あとは[https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#start-mysql]に従い、サービスアカウントの設定からやり直すことでうまく疎通いたしました。